# Query Taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql

I have written an sql query but its taking too much time to get results from table.Around 15000 entries are there in my table.My query and table structure is below..

```
SELECT sp1.sku
FROM `service_prices` AS sp1
WHERE attribute_id = 8 AND
      attribute_value = '100000' AND
      service_id = 2 AND
      sp1.sku IN
      (
          SELECT sp2.sku
          FROM `service_prices` AS sp2
          WHERE attribute_id = 9 AND
                attribute_value = '2' AND
                service_id = 2 AND
                sp2.sku IN
                (
                    SELECT sp3.sku
                    FROM `service_prices` AS sp3
                    WHERE attribute_id = 10 AND
                          attribute_value = 'Haryana' AND
                          service_id = 2
                )
            )
```

[image]

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: please insert new line on your code for easy readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  sp1.sku
 FROM
`service_prices` AS sp1
 INNER JOIN `service_prices` AS sp2 ON sp1.sku= sp2.sku INNER JOIN `service_prices` AS sp3 ON  sp2.sku= sp3.sku
WHERE
sp1.attribute_id = 8
AND sp1.attribute_value = '100000'
AND sp1 service_id = 2 and
sp2.attribute_id = 9
        AND sp2.attribute_value = '2'
        AND sp2.service_id = 2
and 
sp3.attribute_id = 10
                AND sp3.attribute_value = 'Haryana'
                AND sp3.service_id = 2
```

Comment: You should mention that he should add an index on the `sku` column to speed up the joins.  Without this, your answer might not offer any performance improvement.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'service_id = 2 and sp2.attribute_id = 9 AND sp2.attribute_value = '2' ' at line 9

Comment: @aniket Sharma Thanks for your answer its working fine but these attributes are dynamic and how can i make it dynamic.I already put that in loops

Comment: You can use the dynamic sql creation, and execute that sql. Also use Indexing on your columns. Use query plan to track what exactly taking time.